# Biorthogonal complement of subspace of subspace.

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

I'm taking a course on Banach and Hilbert spaces. The teacher who guides the exercise sessions is often a bit fast, so only when revising my notes at home I realize I do not fully understand them.

We were considering the Hilbert space $\mathcal{l}^{2}$ with subspace $\mathcal{l}_{0}$ of all sequences with a finite number of non-zero entries. We were to show that
$$
M = \lbrace x \in \mathcal{l}_{0} \vert \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac{x_{n}}{n + 1} = 0 \rbrace
$$
is a closed subspace of $\mathcal{l}_{0}$ (which I was able to prove myself) and that $M^{\bot \bot \mathcal{l}_{0}}$ is equal to $\mathcal{l}_{0}$.

In my own notes I read
$$
M = ((\frac{1}{n+1})_{n})^{\bot \mathcal{l}_{0}} = ((\frac{1}{n+1})_{n})^{\bot \mathcal{l}^{2}} \cap \mathcal{l}_{0}
$$
Okay so far, but then:
$$
M^{\bot \mathcal{l}_{0}} = ((\frac{1}{n+1})_{n})^{\bot \bot \mathcal{l}^{2}} \cap \mathcal{l}_{0} \\
= \overline{vct\lbrace (\frac{1}{n+1})_{n} \rbrace} \cap \mathcal{l}_{0} \\
= {vct\lbrace (\frac{1}{n+1})_{n} \rbrace} \cap \mathcal{l}_{0} \\
= \lbrace 0 \rbrace
$$
where the second equality uses a property that holds for subsets of Hilbert spaces and the third equality uses that finite dimensional subspaces are closed. It's the first equality that I'm unsure about. How could I motivate it, assuming it's correct at all?

Thank you in advance for you help. Let me know if you need more information.

Nicolas

Answer (score 0):

Note that since
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(n+1)^2} < \infty
$$
by Cauchy-Schwarz, the linear functional
$$
\Lambda: (x_n) \mapsto \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x_n}{n+1}
$$
is a continuous map from $\ell^2 \to \mathbb{C}$ and so $\ker(\Lambda)$ is closed in $\ell^2$, whence $\ker(\Lambda)\cap \ell_0$ is closed in $\ell_0$

Comment: Thank you for you response. However, proving the closedness was not a problem to me, which I might not have stated clearly. Could you perhaps assist me with the second part of my question?